# SQl Query to retrieve data

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot figure out how to get the required data from my table. The query which I wrote shows an error saying subquery returns more than one row..

```
SELECT name  
FROM `business`
WHERE id = (
SELECT business_id
FROM bill 
WHERE id = (
SELECT bill_id
FROM bill_schedule
WHERE show_bill = 1 )
```

Here the subquery for bill_schedule returns more than one row, where show_bill is a boolean column. All I want here is to display the 'name' from the business whose show_bill is set to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `name`  
FROM `business`
WHERE id in (
SELECT business_id
FROM bill 
WHERE id in (
SELECT bill_id
FROM bill_schedule
WHERE show_bill = 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the sub query is returning multiple rows, you can't use an equality operator

Just change the = to IN in your where clause:

```
SELECT name  
FROM `business`
WHERE id IN (
SELECT business_id
FROM bill 
WHERE id IN (
SELECT bill_id
FROM bill_schedule
WHERE show_bill = 1 )
```